# Select node by its text value in xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I am trying to extract the value of the 'Value' node, where the 'Key' node is 'state' within a bash shell:

```
<FrontendStatus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" serializerVersion="1.1">
<script/>
 <State>
  <String>
   ...
   ...
  </String>
  <String>
   ...
   ...
  </String>
  <String>
   <Key>state</Key>
   <Value>WatchingLiveTV</Value>
  </String>
  <String>
   <Key>studiolevels</Key>
   <Value>1</Value>
  </String>
  <String>
   ...
   ...
  </String>
  <String>
   ...
   ...
  </String>
 </State>
</FrontendStatus>
```

I can extract the value if I reference the node directly:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/FrontendStatus[1]/State[1]/String[31]' -v Value <status.xml
WatchingLiveTV
```

But I would like to select it by the value of the 'Key' node instead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This XPath will select `Value` of a `State` based on its `Key` equalling `state`:

```
/FrontendStatus/State/String[Key='state']/Value
```

Or, in xmlstarlet:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/FrontendStatus/State/String[Key='state']" -v Value <status.xml
```

Will return `WatchingLiveTV` as requested.

Comment: Perfect :-) I have fought yesterday a couple of hours with exactly this kind of problem... XPath syntax is arcane. Thanks !

Comment: I think XPath is rather elegant, actually, but glad to have helped regardless!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find that node using the following XPath:

```
/FrontendStatus/State/String[Value = 'WatchingLiveTV']/Value
```

Which will return:

```
<Value>WatchingLiveTV</Value>
```

Note you could also use:

```
//String[Value = 'WatchingLiveTV']/Value
```

Which is slightly smaller.

To select the Value element and parent/siblings, you could use:

```
//String[Value = 'WatchingLiveTV']
```

Which returns:

```
<String>
  <Key>state</Key>
  <Value>WatchingLiveTV</Value>
</String>
```

**Edit**

I just re-read your original question. You would like to select the XML based on the value of the `Key` node. You can do this using the above, but changing the predicate from `Value` to `Key`:

```
//String[Key = 'state']/Value
```

@kjhughes has put this into the syntax format you're after.

I hope that helps.